# How do I do unit tests in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2015, nunit

I have like below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Syncfusion.Gitlab
{
    public class Branches
    {         
        public void CreateBranch(List<string> projectName, string sourceBranch, string destinationBranch)
        {

        }       
        public void CreateTag(List<string> projectName, string sourceBranch,string tagname)
        {

        }       
        public static List<string> GetBranchList(string projectId)
        {            

        }    
        public static List<ProjectData> GetProjectList()
        {

        }
    }
    public class ExcelOperation
    {
        public void GenerateExcel(List<ProjectDetails> finalExcelData, List<string>projectUrl,List<string>tagsorBranchUrl)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I can able to test the method and got the positive output. But I do not know how to test these two method `public static List<string> GetBranchList(string projectId), public static List<ProjectData> GetProjectList()`

My sample test code is below. Below method is successfully passed in `NUnit` test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateTags()
{
    List<string> project = new List<string>();
    project.Add("test1");
    string sourceBranch = "master";
    string tagsName = "v1.0.0";
    branch.CreateTag(project, sourceBranch, tagsName);
}
```

How can I test the that two methods?

**Update:**

I can get the answer with the help of first answer. But Now I have anouther doubt.

How could I test for wrong input? I mean I know that the input I was given Is wrong but I need the green tick mark for that testing. That means the input given is wrong so the output also wrong therfore the testing is right.

In my below image. I need `public void GetBranchListforWrongInput()` also green tick mark. 
 [image]

How could I do it?

Comment: There is not much difference. You test them as you test other method except the fact that you call method over class instead of instance of the class. Did you try this ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes by this I got the answer now! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing static method is pretty much as same as testing non-static methods. It might get complex based on what logic you have in the static method.

But simplest way for your case would be as following.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetBranchList()
{
    string projectId = "someProjectId";
    var result = Branches.GetBranchList(projectId);
    //Assert if result has expected result.
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestGetProjectList()
{
    var result = Branches.GetProjectList();
    //Assert if result has expected result.
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestCreateBranch()
{
    //Prepare TestData
    List<string> projectName = new List<string> {"someProject"};
    string sourceBranch = "sourceBranch"
    string destinationBranch = "destBranch";

    Branches branchesObj = new Branches();
    // Call method by passing the test data.
    branchesObj.CreateBranch(projectName, sourceBranch, destinationBranch);
}
```

This should help you resolve your issue.

Comment: I got it exact answer. I think you probably passed the wrong passed three parameters in `Branches.GetBranchList`

Comment: Oh.. yes.. my bad... I corrected the answer.. Thanks for pointing out..

Comment: You need to assert for non-equality. Something like `Assert.NotEqual`.

Comment: I do not know how to do that. Could you give a demo for `public void CreateBranch(List<string> projectName, string sourceBranch, string destinationBranch)`?

Comment: `CreateBranch` method returns nothing but `void` so you can't actually do Assertion in unit testing of it. You just call the method in the unit test and see it does not break because of any unhandled exception from the method.

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to spend some time learning the fundamentals of Unit Testing before diving directly into it. There are plenty of blogs and articles available on it.